# bootstrapTable: conditional class or applying filter depending on the row values

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have a problem with this [example](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/options/format.html): everything went fine with bootstrapTable [Bootstrap Table example](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#extensions/editable.html) and the code of my editable table (simplified) is:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
                            data: data1,
                            columns: [
                                {
                                    field: 'id',
                                    title: 'id',
                                    editable: {
                                        type: 'text'
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    field: 'info',
                                    title: 'info',
                                    formatter: 'nameFormatter',
                                    editable: {
                                        type: 'text'
                                    },
                                }
                            ]
                        });


function nameFormatter(value, row) {
    var icon = row.id % 2 === 0 ? 'glyphicon-star' : 'glyphicon-star-empty'
    return '<i class="glyphicon ' + icon + '"></i> ' + value;
}
```

However, in the DOM something goes wrong. I get this result (when I see the source):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-name="dependent" data-pk="1" data-value="<i class=" glyphicon="" glyphicon-star-empty"="" class="editable editable-click"> dependent"&gt;</a>
```

The result I expect would be correct and similar to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-name="dependent" data-pk="1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty editable editable-click"> dependent</i></a>
```

Do you know what may be fixed? Seems like there are actually not one but two problems here: html special chars escape and two **class** attributes in within one `<a>`.

The example above uses html.

```
<th data-field="name" data-formatter="nameFormatter">Item Name</th>
```

but I use the javascript solution as you see above as 
`formatter: 'nameFormatter'`.

Any ideas?

**What I'm trying to achieve, as said in the question, but will write one more time so it is clear - I'm trying to add glyficons depending on some values of the rows.** - to add `glyphicon-star` or to add `glyphicon-star-empty` depending on some criteria.

Added per comments below, the results for:

```
console.log(icon);
console.log('<i class="glyphicon ' + icon + '"></i> ' + value);
```

look correct:

```
glyphicon-star-empty
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i> value1
glyphicon-star
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> value143
```

However the result in the DOM is:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-name="dependent" data-pk="1" data-value="<i class=" glyphicon="" glyphicon-star-empty"="" class="editable editable-click"> value1"&gt;</a>
```

which produces:

```
dependent">
```

displayed on the page (wrong HTML markup as you see above).

Comment: can you post the `data1` here?

Comment: can you also `console.log(icon)` and check. I suspect the ternary condition is not getting evaluated properly

Comment: More details added per your questions. also data1 looks correct. Everything works fine until I add a formatter.

Comment: Can you move the formatter up like this : `formatter: function(){.....}` instead of outside the code

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help, still the same result. Thank you.